# Nested relation entity passed to validation with null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a unidirectional relation between `Country` and `Governorate` with the first one being the owner, here are their implementation:

`Country.java`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode

@Entity
public class Country {

    
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 3)
    @NonNull
    @Setter
    private String isoCode;
    
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NonNull
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private List<Governorate> governorates = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

`Governorate.java`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode

@Entity
public class Governorate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private String name;
}
```

And I'm trying to populate the database on startup so i implemented a `CommandLineRunner` class that reads from a **json** file populated with `countries` and their respective `governorates` and maps to a list of `countries` like so:

`CountriesInitializer.java`

```
@Component
public class CountriesInitilizer extends Initializer<Country>{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountriesInitilizer.class);
    
    private static final String JSON_FILE = "com/evalia/backend/countries.json";
    
    @Autowired
    CountryRepository repository;

    @Override
    void preLoad(Class<Country> clazz, String filePath) {
        try (InputStream stream = ResourceUtils.loadResource(filePath)) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<List<Country>> recordTypes = new TypeReference<List<Country>>() {};
            List<Country> countries = mapper.readValue(stream, recordTypes);
            for(Country c: countries) {
                repository.save(c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            InitializationException ex = InitializationException.build(clazz.getName(), e);
            logger.error("Could not pre-load entity!", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        if (!InitializersUtils.isLoaded(repository)) {
            preLoad(Country.class, JSON_FILE);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is whenever i start the application and this initializer begins to save the data it throws a `ConstraintsViolationException` with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.evalia.backend.EvaliaApplication.main(EvaliaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571) ~[spring-orm-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.evalia.backend.initializers.CountriesInitilizer.preLoad(CountriesInitilizer.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.evalia.backend.initializers.CountriesInitilizer.run(CountriesInitilizer.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.7.15-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.evalia.backend.models.Governorate] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.evalia.backend.models.Governorate, messageTemplate='must not be blank'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:801) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:543) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

any ideas ?

**Environment**:
Java: `11`,
Spring-Boot: `2.7.15-SNAPSHOT`

I tried debugging in the `BeanValidationEventListener` as mentioned in the stack where the `Exception` was thrown and i found something interesting, the first entity to be passed for validation is the `Country` instance which comes with it's values in tact, but then when it's the `Governorate`'s turn, they are passed to the validation with their values set to `null`, is this a bug or am i doing something wrong here ?

Thank you.

Comment: Its hard to say what's going wrong here. First I'd check whether the read objects are okay. Put a breakpoint on repository.save(c) and inspect c whether it has valid Governonate objetcs.

Comment: @Karsten already did they are mapped just fine with all the values in tact

Comment: What looks strange to me is that you don't have a @JoinColumn on your relation definition but I can't imagine what effect this would have for your current problem. Another idea is to change the cascade type to ALL. Also I'd check the SQLs going to the database.

Comment: @JoinColumn didn't do much instead the cascade type ALL resolved the problem thank you.